# Disable animation in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, parallels

When I hit Ctrl-Tab, the "Active Tool Window/Files" pop-up animates into place. Its doing my head in. Unlike VS2005, there is no "Disable Animations" under Tools/Options/Environment, which is the only reference googling turns up.

Is there are way to disable this behavior?

So it turns out this has nothing to do with Visual Studio or Windows. It was a Parallels thing - I'm running VS2012 on a Mac.

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=262509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer accessible but the setting still exists in the VS settings file.  Close VS2012 first.  Locate your settings file, mine is stored in C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings

Open the file with a text editor and search for "anim". There's an "AnimationSpeed" setting, mine is 5.  And an "Animations" setting, mine is true.  Try changing it to false, save and start VS again.  Or tinker with the speed, my setting of "5" doesn't do anything that does my head in.  So I don't really know how to test if changing these settings has any effect, but you'll quickly find out.

If you see no effect at all then tinker with the Windows animation settings.

Comment: Changing the number appears to have no effect on the Ctrl-Tab dialog. It was initially 5. I've tried 0 and 20. Also, the Animations setting is "false", so I suspect its not related to the Ctrl-Tab dialog. Thanks for pointing me to that file though. I'm sure it will come in useful.

Comment: Hmm. If I edit that file, and run VS, the number is set back to 5.

Comment: Where are the Window animation settings?

Comment: I don't know your Windows version.  Use google for trivial queries, just type "windows animation settings".  First page of hits covers them all.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't it. It was Parallels. Serves me right for running VS2012 on a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

Open Tools->Options->General 
Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" 
Uncheck "Enable rich client visual experience"

This toggles the Animations property value in C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings to false